# How to take the cumulative maximum of a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "realization_id": np.repeat([0, 1], 6),
    "sample_size": np.tile([0, 1, 2], 4),
    "num_obs": np.tile(np.repeat([25, 100], 3), 2),
    "accuracy": [0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7],
    "prob": [0.94, 0.96, 0.95, 0.98, 0.93, 0.92, 0.90, 0.92, 0.95, 0.9, 0.91, 0.92]
})

df["accum_max_prob"] = df.groupby(["realization_id", "num_obs"])["prob"].cummax()
```

And I want to know how to create a column with this output:

```
df["desired_accuracy"] = [0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7]
```

Each entry of `desired_accuracy` equals the `accuracy` value that corresponds to the row where the highest `prob` has been achieved so far by group (that is why I create `accum_max_prob`).

So, for example: the first value is `0.8` because there is no data prior to that, but then the next one is `0.7` because the `prob` of the second row is greater than the first. The third value stays the same, because the third `prob` is lower than the second one, so it does not update `desired_accuracy`. For each pair `(realization_id, num_obs)` the criteria resets.

How can I do it in a vectorized fashion using Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like:

```
df['desired_accuracy'] = df['accuracy'].mask(df['prob'].lt(df['accum_max_prob'])).ffill()
```

Output:

```
    realization_id  sample_size  num_obs  accuracy  prob  accum_max_prob  desired_accuracy
0                0            0       25       0.8  0.94            0.94               0.8
1                0            1       25       0.7  0.96            0.96               0.7
2                0            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.96               0.7
3                0            0      100       0.6  0.98            0.98               0.6
4                0            1      100       0.7  0.93            0.98               0.6
5                0            2      100       0.5  0.92            0.98               0.6
6                1            0       25       0.6  0.90            0.90               0.6
7                1            1       25       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7
8                1            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.95               0.8
9                1            0      100       0.7  0.90            0.90               0.7
10               1            1      100       0.9  0.91            0.91               0.9
11               1            2      100       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df["desired_accuracy_2"] = (
    df.groupby(["realization_id", "num_obs", "accum_max_prob"])["accuracy"]
    .transform("first")
)
```

Prints:

```
    realization_id  sample_size  num_obs  accuracy  prob  accum_max_prob  desired_accuracy  desired_accuracy_2
0                0            0       25       0.8  0.94            0.94               0.8                 0.8
1                0            1       25       0.7  0.96            0.96               0.7                 0.7
2                0            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.96               0.7                 0.7
3                0            0      100       0.6  0.98            0.98               0.6                 0.6
4                0            1      100       0.7  0.93            0.98               0.6                 0.6
5                0            2      100       0.5  0.92            0.98               0.6                 0.6
6                1            0       25       0.6  0.90            0.90               0.6                 0.6
7                1            1       25       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7                 0.7
8                1            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.95               0.8                 0.8
9                1            0      100       0.7  0.90            0.90               0.7                 0.7
10               1            1      100       0.9  0.91            0.91               0.9                 0.9
11               1            2      100       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7                 0.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Just keep the values where `prob` and `accum_max_prob` are equal and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['desired_accuracy'] = df['accuracy'].where(df['accum_max_prob'].eq(df['prob'])).ffill()
```

Note that you don't need to `ffill` per group, **provided that there was no missing value in `prob` originally.** If there were missing values, use `df['accuracy'].where(df['accum_max_prob'].eq(df['prob'])).groupby([df["realization_id"], df["num_obs"]]).ffill()`

Output:

```
    realization_id  sample_size  num_obs  accuracy  prob  accum_max_prob  desired_accuracy
0                0            0       25       0.8  0.94            0.94               0.8
1                0            1       25       0.7  0.96            0.96               0.7
2                0            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.96               0.7
3                0            0      100       0.6  0.98            0.98               0.6
4                0            1      100       0.7  0.93            0.98               0.6
5                0            2      100       0.5  0.92            0.98               0.6
6                1            0       25       0.6  0.90            0.90               0.6
7                1            1       25       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7
8                1            2       25       0.8  0.95            0.95               0.8
9                1            0      100       0.7  0.90            0.90               0.7
10               1            1      100       0.9  0.91            0.91               0.9
11               1            2      100       0.7  0.92            0.92               0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

df['desired_accuracy'] = df['accuracy'].where(df['accum_max_prob'].eq(df['prob'])).ffill()